# Websphere : Start server with Authentication failed when using LTPA. The exception is <null>

Tags: java, websphere, application-server, websphere-6.1, ltpa

From last 2 days I am struggling with below error in my local windows7 machine, I have IBM WebSphere Application Server - Express 6.1.0.27 installed in my local where I deployed my application successfully, while starting the server everything works fine except below error which keep repeated like a loop.... I googled many site with no luck.. I also re installed db2 (DB2 9.7 fp2), and WAS but problem still persist.
Any help will really appreciated !!

```
[6/3/14 20:42:43:939 IST] 00000012 LTPAServerObj E   SECJ0369E: Authentication failed when using LTPA. The exception is <null>.
[6/3/14 20:42:43:984 IST] 00000012 LTPAServerObj E   SECJ0369E: Authentication failed when using LTPA. The exception is <null>.
[6/3/14 20:42:43:988 IST] 00000012 RoleBasedAuth A   SECJ0305I: The role-based authorization check failed for admin-authz operation Server:getName.  The user UNAUTHENTICATED (unique ID: UNAUTHENTICATED) was not granted any of the following required roles: adminsecuritymanager, operator, deployer, administrator, monitor, configurator.
[6/3/14 20:42:48:537 IST] 00000012 LTPAServerObj E   SECJ0369E: Authentication failed when using LTPA. The exception is <null>.
[6/3/14 20:42:48:592 IST] 00000012 LTPAServerObj E   SECJ0369E: Authentication failed when using LTPA. The exception is <null>.
[6/3/14 20:42:48:596 IST] 00000012 RoleBasedAuth A   SECJ0305I: The role-based authorization check failed for admin-authz operation Server:getName.  The user UNAUTHENTICATED (unique ID: UNAUTHENTICATED) was not granted any of the following required roles: adminsecuritymanager, operator, deployer, administrator, monitor, configurator.
[6/3/14 20:42:52:934 IST] 00000012 LTPAServerObj E   SECJ0369E: Authentication failed when using LTPA. The exception is <null>.
[6/3/14 20:42:52:963 IST] 00000012 LTPAServerObj E   SECJ0369E: Authentication failed when using LTPA. The exception is <null>.
```

Answer (score 1):

Matches with below apar PM34097
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM34097

You can check by upgrading to the WAS version mentioned there i.e 61039